# cannot access new drive through nfs

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, mount

I am running nfs-kernel-server to access my files on my linux machine(ubuntu - /share). The disk I have been using is full. So I have added a new disk and mounted it to /share/data. My other pc mounts the /share folder to /mnt/nfs; but cannot see the contents of /mnt/nfs/data. I have tried adding /share/data to /etc/exports, but it did not help. What do I do?

PS: I am looking for another solution than explicitly mounting /share/data on the second drive.

Answer (score 0):

NFSv4 supports nested mounts as you described, you can switch to it, but there are some issues. Otherwise, you must explicitly mount /share/data on each client.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `nohide` export option, but it has caveats. Read the `exports(5)` man page for more details.